# Delay iframe display until new iframe is loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I have an iframe that I want to change it's source URL after 7 seconds. The problem is when I do, there is a period where the iframe content disappears as the new source URL is being loaded.

This is my iframe:

```
<iframe src="http://someurl1.com" width="875" height="550" frameborder="0" id="anim"></iframe>
```

And this is the code I'm currently using to change the src:

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function () {
        setTimeout(function(){ 
            document.getElementById("anim").src = 'http://someurl2.com';
        }, 7000);       
    });
```

Ideally I'd like to have it fadeout/in for the new URL, but I'd be happy to start with getting it so there's no blank space as the second URL loads!

Comment: @Joe - I tried that. The problem is the URL loads an animation and for some reason the second animation won't initiate when I do it this way.

Answer (score 0):

What you could do, is to use a second IFrame. After 7 second you load the second IFrame. On the onload event of that second IFrame, you hide the first one and show the second one.

This is a work around but it should do what you need.

Comment: Thanks, but please see my previous comment: I tried that. The problem is the URL loads an animation and for some reason the second animation won't initiate when I do it this way.

Comment: Sorry it wasn't clear from your comment that it was this strategy you tried. It is indeed strange that the animation does not trigger when you do it like this. Do you maybe have code examples to add?